# merge all divs as a single image and upload it to server as a jpg file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am having the divs bellow:

```
<div style="width:800px; height:420px; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:10; background-image: url('https://3t27ch3qjjn74dw66o1as187-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/052516-800x420-vege-Wallpaper.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat;">

<div style="width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:30px; left:100px; z-index:10; background-image: url('https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/useravatars/2793079.gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>

<div style="width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:30px; left:300px; z-index:10; background-image: url('https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/useravatars/2793079.gif'); background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>


<div style="width:200px; height:30px; position:absolute; top:210px; left:300px; z-index:10; font-size:40px; color:#000; text-align:center;">SOME TEXT</div>

</div>
```

is there any possibility to merge them as a single image and upload it to server?

I tried html5 canvas but a lot of times it returns a blank image.
Is it possible to do this with another way?

It's important to keep the z-index of each div and position

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

First get html2pdf https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf

```
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../vendor/autoload.php';
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\Html2PdfException;
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Exception\ExceptionFormatter;

$html_content = '<div style="width:800px; height:420px; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:10; background-image: url(\'https://3t27ch3qjjn74dw66o1as187-wpengine.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/052516-800x420-vege-Wallpaper.jpg\'); background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:30px; left:100px; z-index:10; background-image: url(\'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/useravatars/2793079.gif\'); background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; position:absolute; top:30px; left:300px; z-index:10; background-image: url(\'https://myanimelist.cdn-dena.com/images/useravatars/2793079.gif\'); background-repeat:no-repeat;"></div>
<div style="width:200px; height:30px; position:absolute; top:210px; left:300px; z-index:10; font-size:40px; color:#000; text-align:center;">SOME TEXT</div>
</div>';

## get html2pdf https://github.com/spipu/html2pdf
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4');
$html2pdf->writeHTML($html_content);
$file = $html2pdf->Output('temp.pdf','F');

 # CONVERT PDF TO IMAGE
$im = new imagick('temp.pdf');
$im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
$img_name = time().'.jpg';
$im->setSize(800,600);
$im->writeImage($img_name);
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Comment: Chase it througs me an 500 error... even if i ran the examples that is inside exemples folder of Html2Pdf.. Any idea?

Comment: Check php_error.log  you may need some libraries like gd